# Matrix to power $2012$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

How to calculate $A^{2012}$?

$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&-1&-2\\2&0&-2\\2&-1&-1\end{array}\right]$

How can one calculate this? It must be tricky or something, cause there was only 1 point for solving this.

Comment: BTW, matrices like this are called *idempotent*.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Observe that $A^2$ is $A$.

So $A^{\large2012}$ is $A$ too.

Comment: How do you observe this?

Comment: just multiply A with A

Answer (score 23):

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&-1&-2\\2&0&-2\\2&-1&-1\end{array}\right]$$
$$A^2=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&-1&-2\\2&0&-2\\2&-1&-1\end{array}\right]\cdot \left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&-1&-2\\2&0&-2\\2&-1&-1\end{array}\right]$$

$$A^2 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}{9-2-4}&{-3+2}&{-6+2+2}\\{6-4}&{-2+2}&{-4+2}\\{6-2}&{-2+1}&{-4+2+1}\end{array}\right]$$
$$A^2 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&-1&-2\\2&0&-2\\2&-1&-1\end{array}\right]$$
$$A^2=A$$

$$A=A^2=A^3=\cdots =A^n,n\in N$$

so $$A^{2012}=A$$

Answer (score 19):

Hints:

- Diagonalize ([*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)) the matrix $A = P J P^{-1}$
- Take advantage of the diagonalization, such that $A^{2012} = P J^{2012} P^{-1}$

Comment: Awesome hints! $+1^{2012}$

Comment: This was my first thought as well, and it's one of the more general approaches for problems of this type, but as others have pointed out there's a shortcut in this specific case.

Comment: @DylanYott: thanks, regards

Answer (score 11):

This particular example, as noted above, is easy.

More generally, you could use a technique called "[exponentiation via squaring.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)" (Since the first step of this operation is to square $A$, it would lead you immediately to see that $A^2=A$, so you wouldn't have to do the entire operation.)

Or you could write out the characteristic polynomial $p(x)=\det(x I-A)$. Then divide the polynomial $x^{2012}$ by $p(x)$ to get a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$. That is:

$$x^{2012} = p(x)q(x) + r(x)$$

Then $A^{2012} = r(A)$. So you only have to compute $A^2$ to and $r(x)$ to figure out $A^{2012}$.

(The polynomial division might seem like it requires more operations than the "exponentiation by squaring," but it's actually pretty much equivalent, I believe - there is a way to compute $r(x)$ that is equivalent to "exponentiation by squaring.")

Comment: I don't think your last parenthesised sentence is correct. Provided $p(x)$ has easy and distinct roots, you can find $r(x)$ by substituting the three roots (which makes the term $p(x)q(x)$ vanish) and solving the resulting linear system for the coefficients of $r(x)$. This is not equivalent to repeated squaring, but rather to diagonalising $A$ and evaluating $A^{2012}$ that way. There is a variation of the method for repeated roots, just like one can manage eigenvalues with multiplicity, but the eigenvalues themselves have to be simple for this to be doable.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Sure, if you have "easy and distinct roots." I was talking about the general case, and the fact that the division algorithm is at least as easy as the repeated squaring. In some instances, you can make it faster, definitely.

Answer (score 9):

This particular matrix satisfies $A^2 = A$. Thus $A^{2012} = A$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

Write $A$ as:
$$A=C^{-1}BC$$

where $B$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues.

Then do the computation.