# Finding Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors weird equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have matrix:
$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&-1&-2\\2&0&-2\\2&-1&-1\end{array}\right]$

And I have to find eigenvalues and coresponding eigenvectors.

I get $det(A-xI_3) = -x(x-1)^2$, so eigenvalues are $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 1$

Now I want to find coresponding eigenvectors. I get:

$A - 0I_3 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}3&-1&-2\\2&0&-2\\2&-1&-1\end{array}\right] $ 
and
$A  - I_3= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&-1&-2\\2&-1&-2\\2&-1&-2\end{array}\right]$

To first equation I have solution $y = x, z = x$, but I dont know what eigenvectors are and to the second I dont even know the solution to equation $(A-I_3)[x,y,z]^T$. Could you help me?

Comment: That should be $\det(A-xI)$, not $\det(A)$.

Comment: Just consider equations $2 \cdot x - y - 2 \cdot z = 0$. These are for example, $[x,y,z] = [1, 0, 1]$ and $[x,y,z] = [1,2,0]$. These ones are the basis of eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: @Naimads: Have you learned about algebraic and geometric multiplicity? Actually, the eigenvectors, as noted in comments, are very well behaved, but you got the eigenvalues wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the eigenvalues, you can consider finding a basis of the eigenvectors associated to each eigenvalues, which means resolving (with Gauss method) this equation (for the 0 eigenvalue) :
$X=
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \in E_0 \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
3x-y-2z&=0 \\ 
2x-2z&=0 \\ 
2x-y-z&=0
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow AX=0.X$

$\begin{cases}
3x-y-2z&=0 \\ 
2x-2z&=0 \\ 
2x-y-z&=0
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
2x-y-z&=0 \\ 
-y+z&=0 \\ 
0&=0
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in \{\begin{pmatrix}s\\s\\s\end{pmatrix},s\in\mathbb{K}\}$

Finally :
$E_0 = Vect(\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix})$

The case of the eigenvalue 1 starts exactly the same way  :
$X=
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \in E_1 \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
3x-y-2z&=x \\ 
2x-2z&=y \\ 
2x-y-z&=z
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow AX=1.X$ and you find the above eigenvectors ;-).

So, you have to find a basis of the plane : $P: 2x-y-2z=0$.

One way is to parameter the problem :
$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in P \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in \lbrace\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}s+t\\s\\t\end{pmatrix},(s,t)\in\mathbb{K}\rbrace$

So you find immediately that $E_1 = Vect(\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix})$

This is the classic method of resolution.

Comment: It might be easier to parameterize it as $[s,2s-2t,t]^T$, since $y=2x-2z$.

Comment: Yes :-). The result is however the same.

Answer (score 3):

Since, from [your previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429971/matrix-to-power-a2012), we know that $A^2=A$, that gives us that each column vector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$. (Note the column matrices are not linearly independent.)

An eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ can be found via inspection: $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Ok but what about eigenvalue of $0$?

Comment: @Naimads Typo had me saying $1$ instead of $0$. The second paragraph gave a case for eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Do I get rigtht that eigenvectors for eigenvalue of $0$ can be $[1,1,1]$ or $[2,2,2]$ or $[12,12,12]$etc.?

Comment: Yes, the space of vectors of eigenvalue $0$ is the vectors $[x,x,x]^T$

Comment: I can't say how Piotr got his values, but $[1,0,1]^T$ is just $-1$ times the middle column. Any (non-zero) constant times an eigenvector is an eigenvector is an eigenvector. Any linear combination of eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue is also an eigenvector. And $[1,2,0]^T=v_1+2v_2$ where $v_1$ is the first column and $v_2$ is the second.

Comment: This answer is nice. +1

Comment: I got my answers just be definition of eigenvector: for matrix $A$ the eigenvector $v$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the solution of system of linear equations $(A - \lambda \cdot I) \cdot v = 0$. In another words, dot product of matrix $(A - \lambda \cdot I)$ rows and vector $v$ vanishes. So I have got the equation $2x - y - 2z = 0$ for $[x, y, z]$ being the eigenvector we are looking for. Setting $x$ to $1$ you can got the eigenvectors $[1, 0, 1]$ and $[1, 2, 0]$ correspondingly.